# Makefile strange variable substitution

Tags: make

My `Makefile` looks like this:

```
%.foo: %.bar
    cp $< $@

test: *.foo
    echo *.foo
```

I have 2 files in the directory: `a.bar` and `b.bar`. When I run `make test` it outputs:

```
cp b.bar *.foo
echo *.foo
*.foo
```

It also creates a file `*.foo` in the current directory.

I am actually expecting to see this:

```
cp a.bar a.foo
cp b.bar b.foo
echo *.foo
a.foo b.foo
```

And also creating `a.foo` and `b.foo`. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you need to handle wildcards explicitly, with the `wildcard` function (at least in [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html)):

```
%.foo: %.bar
    cp $< $@

foos = $(patsubst %.bar,%.foo,$(wildcard *.bar))

test: $(foos)
    echo $(foos)
```

`$(wildcard *.bar)` expands to all the files ending in `.bar`, the `patsubst` call replaces `.bar` with `.foo`, and all the targets are then processed as you’d expect.

Answer (score 6):

There is no *.foo file to begin with. So what make does is look for how to make `*.foo` literaly and the first rule does this. Make expands `$<` to the first pre-requisite (`*.bar`, which happens to be `b.bar` in this case). Make then runs the shell command `cp b.bar *.foo`. Since there is no *.foo, shell expands it to `cp b.bar *.foo` literally. That's how you get a `*.foo` file.

You can verify this by running `make -d test`.

You can get the effect you want by generating the list of targets based on list of prerequisites.

```
TARGETS = $(patsubst %.bar,%.foo,$(wildcard *.bar))
%.foo: %.bar
    @cp $< $@
test: $(TARGETS)
    @echo $(TARGETS)
    echo *.foo
```